# Добавление объекта в базу дынных

Tags: java, база-данных

Есть простой каласс

```
public class User {
private int id;
private String name;
private String password;

public User(String name, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
}
```

так же есть метод

```
public void addUser(User user) {
    users.add(user);
    try {
        userDao.addUser(user.getName(), user.getPassword());
    } catch (DaoException e) {
        System.out.println("Error adding user to database");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("User " + user + " was added");
}
```

Метод добавляет в базу пользователя. В базе я сделал таблицу `id, name, password`. В таблице установил поле `id`как автоИнкремент объект я собираю без поля `id`, а уже в базе он лежит с `id` который ему присвоила база(id не повторяются). Вопрос в следующем - правильный ли подход у меня? Ведь если мне нужен этот объект(а собрать его полностью получится только считав с базы), то мне нужно получается получив имя и пароль собрать объект, положить в базу(там ему присвоится id), а потом уже достать его с базы и собрать окончательно. Как делают это на практике? Если еще раз сформулировать вопрос - когда и как правильно инициализировать `id`что бы это поле оставалось уникальное для объектов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подход должен определяться в зависимости от того, какая дальнейшая роль у твоего объекта: его настигнет сборщик мусора, либо ты продолжаешь использовать его в программе. В первом случае, не имеет критического значения, как ты будешь оперировать *id*. На второй вариант, припасен отдельный стейтмент для получения айдишника, который сгенерировала база, без повторного обращения к ней, а именно `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`
К примеру ты можешь использовать *PreparedStatement* и передать вторым аргументом в функцию как раз стейтмент для возвращения сгенерированного ключа.
Пример:

```
    String QUERY = "insert into persons (name, password) values (?,?)";
try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
    statement.setString(1, user.getName());
statement.setString(2, user.getPass());
    statement.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
      if(rs.next()) {
         user.setId(rs.getInt(1));
      }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    
}
```

Comment: спасибо, переосмыслив свой вопрос я понял, что ваш ответ именно то что мне было нужно!